# global name 'json' is not defined

Tags: python, json, maya

Here is the beginning of createPeliMelo.py

```
def creation(path,session):

    myPathFile=path+session+'.txt'
    print myPathFile
    pelimeloFile = open(path+session+'.txt', 'r')

    with pelimeloFile as inf:    
        data = json.loads(inf.read())
```

Here is my Python script inside Maya:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import json
import os
from itertools import islice
import createPeliMelo as PeliMelo

PeliMelo.creation('C:/Users/francesco/Desktop/pelimelo video printemps/','session5723')
```

Here is the error I got:

> Error: line 1: NameError: file C:/Users/francesco/Documents/maya/2016/scripts\createPeliMelo.py line
>   17: global name 'json' is not defined #

Line 17 is: `data = json.loads(inf.read())`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You need to `import json` in createPeliMelo.py

Answer (score 7):

When you import something, that import only applies to the file that you imported it in. This means that if you want to use `json` in `createPeliMelo.py` you need to do `import json` in THAT file, not your second script. Imports from one file will not propagate over to another.

Comment: def creation(path,session):
    import json    
    import maya.cmds as cmds
    import json
    import os

Comment: @fransua Put the imports at the very top of the file.

Comment: it works... except that now I have a new error message : " global name 'cmds' is not defined # " though I have also added "import maya.cmds as cmds"